# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Update a One to Many Relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two Models:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    info = db.Column(db.Text(255))

    post = db.relationship('Post', backref=db.backref('projects'))

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    headline = db.Column(db.String(64))
    content = db.Column(db.Text(255))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    projectId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'))
```

If I, e.g., create an instance of post and append it to a project via `projectInstance.append(post(headline="...", content="..."))`
 Now  I want to update the project to which the post should belong to. Is there an easier way besides querying the desired project, append the post to it and remove it from the old project?

```
oldProject.remove(post)
newProject.append(post)
```

Comment: I think you have the singular and plural in your relationship naming the wrong way around, since a `Post` can reference only 1 `Project`, but a project can be referenced by many posts in your model.

Comment: Thats a good point, you having there. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it the other way around: use the back reference in `Post`:

```
post.projects = newProject
```

This'll handle the required session management. Here's a minimal example:

```
In [2]: class A(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'a'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   ...:     bs = relationship('B', backref='a')
   ...:

In [3]: class B(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'b'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   ...:     a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
   ...:

In [5]: a1 = A()

In [6]: a2 = A()

In [7]: b = B()

In [8]: a1.bs.append(b)

In [9]: a1.bs
Out[9]: [<__main__.B at 0x7f7322fb52b0>]

In [10]: b.a = a2

In [11]: a1.bs, a2.bs
Out[11]: ([], [<__main__.B at 0x7f7322fb52b0>])
```

Also just appending the `post` instance to the `newProject.post` collection handles removing automatically, as can be seen with our as and bs:

```
In [9]: a1.bs.append(b)

In [10]: a1.bs, a2.bs
Out[10]: ([<__main__.B at 0x7f26702565f8>], [])

In [11]: a2.bs.append(b)

In [12]: a1.bs, a2.bs
Out[12]: ([], [<__main__.B at 0x7f26702565f8>])
```